# hierarchy to blockdiagram using perl

Tags: perl

I have structured hierarchy of different files and sub-files. I would like to convert it to block diagram.

Now question is - Does perl supports this type of idea directly or indirectly?

If you know any other solution/work-around please share it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is a block diagram?

Answer (score 3):

You can look into [GraphViz](http://www.graphviz.org). Here is an [introduction](http://www.linuxjournal.com/node/7275/print) and [CPAN link](http://search.cpan.org/dist/GraphViz/). And example code from some source I don't know:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use IO::Dir;
use GraphViz;
use GraphViz::Small;
use GraphViz::No;

my $directory = './';

my $graph = GraphViz::No->new(directed => 0, layout => 'twopi');

walk($directory);

sub walk {
  my($dir, $parent) = @_;
  $graph->add_node($dir) unless defined $parent;
  my $d = IO::Dir->new($dir);
  foreach my $file ($d->read) {
    next if $file =~ /^\./;
    if (-f $dir . $file) {
      $graph->add_node($dir . $file, label => $file);
      $graph->add_edge($dir => $dir . $file);
    } elsif (-d $dir . $file) {
      $graph->add_node($dir . $file . '/', label => $file . '/');
      $graph->add_edge($dir => $dir . $file . '/');
      walk($dir . $file . '/', $dir);
    }
  }
}

$graph->as_png("directories.png");
```